# Identify multiple occurrence and positions of a character or a number or special character in a string in MS Access SQL

Tags: ms-access

I have a table in MS Access with a column as Reference_Number.  In it, data is stored as plain numbers, and numbers + special character (e.g. 1234|789|004).  Location of "|" is floating i.e, it can be anywhere in the string.

I need to convert the string that lies in between two delimiters e.g. in the above case convert 789 to .000789 and add it to the string that lies before the delimiter.  I do not need the string that lies after the second delimiter.

any suggestion and ideas how to do this in MS ACCESS SQL?

Thanks,

AOB

Comment: How many records are there?

Comment: That is right.  Records I have are 500K+.  And it will increase with time

Comment: My solution is (which is not elegant): select ref_nbr, instr(REF_NBR,'|')+1 as 1st_delimiter, instr(1st_delimiter,REF_NBR,'|') -1 as 2nd_delimiter, 2nd_delimiter-1st_delimiter as decimal_part,
cdbl(mid(REF_NBR,1st_delimiter,decimal_part+1)/1000) from table_A where REF_NBR like '%|%'

Answer (score 0):

SELECT
REF_NBR,
cdbl(left(REF_NBR,(instr(REF_NBR,'|')-1)))+
cdbl(mid(REF_NBR,instr(REF_NBR,'|')+1,(instr((instr(REF_NBR,'|')+1),REF_NBR,'|') - (instr(REF_NBR,'|')+1)))/1000)
FROM table_a